# Hardhat - Interacting with deployed contract

Tags: hardhat

So I verified the deploy script and contract validity through Remix. And if I run through the same set of steps within the Hardhat console, I'm seeing the correct value set.

The problem is that when I run the javascript script by doing `npx hardhat run scripts/setter.js`, it's not setting the value correctly and not showing up in Etherscan. I'm not seeing any errors as well.

Here's my script below:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
    const value = process.env.VALUE;
    const contractAddress = process.env.CONTRACT_ADDRESS;

    const MyContract = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("HelloWorld");
    const myContract = MyContract.attach(contractAddress);

    await myContract.setBytes32(value);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you say you run the script using this command `npx hardhat run scripts/setter.js`
This means the command is being run locally and not on the testnet network.

For that, you would need to add the network in your hardhat config like this.

```
 networks: {
    Goerli: {
           url: `https://goerli.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_PROJECT_ID}`, 
           //use any rpc provider, infura is not necessary
           accounts:[PRIVATEKEY] //Make sure you use .env and not actually keep 
           your private key here.
  },
}
```

and then you will run the command like this

```
npx hardhat run scripts/setter.js --network Goerli
```

This way hardhat will connect to the testnet and perform the function.